# See advertisers targeting my site

Tags: google-adsense

Is there any way to see, in AdSense, what advertisers are targeting my website? I see a lot of ads from the same advertiser/company and I think that they basically targeted my website, which I disagree because of various reasons.

Comment: Short answer. No. Short of visiting your own site which I do not recommend, Adsense and Google do not want you to know who the advertisers are for the advertisers sake and so that you do not try and manipulate the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit your website once in a blue moon with a new browser configuration every time, then chances are you'll see the true advertisers. Also, if you visit your website from another computer, you may see true advertisers.

If however you refresh the page frequently or you visit multiple pages of your own site in a short time frame, then theres a high chance you'll see either unrelated ads and/or low-quality ads targeting your website. I think this is because google doesn't want to see people causing an artificial increase in impressions.